# Org-mode #+include: -- ignore configuration lines from included file

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

How can I have org #+INCLUDE: ignore configurations from the included files? I'm thinking of cases where I don't want Latex Classes to be messed up. For example, if I have two org files book.org and chapter.org that look like the following:

book.org

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: book
* Chapter 1
#+INCLUDE: chapter.org
```

chapter.org

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: report
* Results
```

Then on export (to another Org file) I get the following:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: book
* Chapter 1
#+LATEX_CLASS: report
** Results
```

This is not good because a latex-export may get messed up (the last latex_class takes precedence, so I would end up with a report and not a book). What is the recommended way to avoid these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Use the include directive's option: :only-contents t (https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html), for example in book.org:

```
* Chapter 1    
** Results
#+INCLUDE: "chapter.org::*Results"
```

Then only the contents below the header Results in chapter.org is included.

If you are specifying your latex class in an export property in chapter.org, like below

```
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_LaTeX_CLASS: some class
:END:
```

then you can also include the whole org file

```
#+include: "chapter.org" :only-contents t
```

Comment: This does not work. All latex_headers, for example, are included with the file.

Comment: @dangom you're right, sorry edited my Answer.

Comment: This solution is not completely satisfactory, as I do not want to select a specific heading, but rather filter out some boilerplate without knowing in advance how much boilerplate it is.

Comment: @dangom: Then you should change your approach and specify your latex class in a property.

Answer (score 1):

I would reorg the files a bit: the `chapter1.org` and `report.org` files should not specify any configuration. You can then include them in `Book.org`:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: book

#+INCLUDE: chapter1.org
#+INCLUDE: report.org
```

or in `Report.org` (note the capital R: I'm assuming your filesystem is case sensitive):

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: report

#+INCLUDE: report.org
```

This requires a bit more effort and discipline, but it *is* flexible.